# Accessing variables from within a function

Tags: python, psychopy

I'm displaying some stimuli and then checking for keypresses via a keypress function, but I can't seem to be able to access the variables in that function e.g. Quit is supposed to be initiated if the user presses Q during key checks, and if the user presses 'g', running turns to '2' which is supposed to exit the overall while loop. I have tried using global variables, but I still could not get it to work, I'm also aware that global variables are considred risky.

```
def check_keys():
    allKeys = event.getKeys(keyList = ('g','h','escape'))
    for thisKey in allKeys:
        if thisKey == 'escape':
            dataFile.close()
            window.close()
            core.quit()
        elif thisKey == 'g':
             keyTime=core.getTime()
             thisResp = 1      
        elif thisKey == 'h':
             keyTime=core.getTime()
             thisResp = 0    

thisResp = 2
running = 1
while running == 1:

    for frame in range(frames):
        fix.draw()
        upper_target.draw()
        z= window.flip()
        check_keys()
        if thisResp == 1:
            running = 2:

print running
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is your actual code? Indenting is important in Python.

Comment: No, if that was my code I'd have indentation errors. I edited it now though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `thisResp` is not defined before the `check_keys()` method, the method is not going to change the value of `thisRep`. In order to change the value of `thisResp`, I would either pass it as an argument to the `check_keys()`, or have `check_keys()` return either 1 or 0 and then set the value of `thisResp` to what's return. Your code would look like the following using the second approach:

```
def check_keys():
    allKeys = event.getKeys(keyList = ('g','h','escape'))
    for thisKey in allKeys:
        if thisKey == 'escape':
            dataFile.close()
            window.close()
            core.quit()
        elif thisKey == 'g':
            keyTime=core.getTime()
            return 1      
        elif thisKey == 'h':
            keyTime=core.getTime()
            return 0
       return 2

thisResp = 2
running = 1
while running == 1:

    for frame in range(frames):
        fix.draw()
        upper_target.draw()
        z= window.flip()
        thisResp = check_keys()
        if thisResp == 1:
            running = 2
            break

print running
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. When a key is pressed, and running changes to 2, it isn't breaking out of the while loop for some reason. Is it possible to break out 2 loops?

Comment: How many `frames` are there? If you add a `print(running)` at the end of every for loop do you see that it's value has changed?

Comment: 60 frames (1 second). Yes the value of running is changing, but it isn't breaking out of the loop. I even changed the frames to make 10 seconds so it would be obvious when I broke out of the loop, but nothing happened. I still had to wait for all of the frames to elapse.

Comment: The value of `running` is checked only only after the  `for frame in range(frames):` loop completes. That check needs to be moved within that loop if you want to use it to exit that loop. i.e. currently `running = 2` will terminate the `while` loop but not the `for` loop it encompasses.

Comment: @Steve: You can put a `break` statement inside that `if thisResp == 1:` block in the `for` loop, after the `running = 2` statement. Note that you need to get rid of the trailing `:` after the 2 in that statement or you'll get a syntax error.

Comment: Ah, that was it. Thank you all.